# Android Studio - Virtual Device takes too much disk space even with default settings (4x more space than normal)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I create a Virtual Device in Android Studio, it takes `4+ GB` of disk space when freshly created with the default settings. It normally takes between `500MB` and `1.5GB` as I could see on some other questions related to Virtual Devices and the screenshots of the official Android documentation.

Here's a screenshot of my devices when freshly created with default settings:

`My Virtual Devices`

[image: My Virtual Devices]

As you see, the `Pixel phone` is taking `4.5GB` of space and the `Nexus 5X` is taking `4.3GB`.

Also, we did exact same process with a colleague and here's a screenshot of her freshly created Virtual Devices:

`My colleague's Virtual Devices`

[image: My colleague's Virtual Devices]

As you can see, in her case, the `Pixel phone` is taking `503MB` and the `Nexus 5X` is taking `1.1GB`.

We both used the same default settings as you can see here:

`Virtual Devices settings 1`

[image: Virtual Devices settings 1]

`Virtual Devices settings 2`

[image: Virtual Devices settings 2]

**We both have the same platforms:**

`MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6`

`Android Studio 3.1.3`

Does anyone have idea of what is generating this oversizing on my Virtual Devices?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is because it is saving the state of your last work.

Comment: Hi Umang, i don't think that's the reason because the size that i describe is when the Virtual Device is newly created. When i work during the day, it gets up to 6GB, and at the end of the day i select "Wipe Data" from the virtual devices options and they return to  ~4.5GB.

Comment: Oh, well I'm using an iMac and while creating it was 4.5 GB and slowly it went now upto 10 GB. I do not care about the space bcoz I have 1TB flash drive.. So at the end while closing, I just made an assumption. okay may be there is something else then. All the best.

Comment: Hi Umang, today i accidentally solved the issue. Now my newly created devices start at 1 GB and not at 4.5 GB. I'm going to post the solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today i accidentally solved the issue. I needed to perform some updates on the Android Studio while installing some libraries and i updated:

`Android Platform SDK 28` (which was the one i was using for my Virtual Devices) to `Revision 6` and the `Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image` for that SDK to `Revison 5`.

I also updated the `Android SDK Platform Tools` to `28.0.1`, the `Android SDK Tools` to `26.1.1` and the `Intel x86 Emulator Accelelator (HAXM Installer`) to `7.3.0`.

Then, i needed to test on another Virtual Device and it was created and ran starting at `1.0 GB`. So i decided to delete my current devices and create them again after this update. I created once again the two Virtual Devices that are show above on the question and the results were the following:

- Pixel phone -> Now starts at `1.0 GB`
- Nexus 5X phone -> Now starts at `1.1 GB`

Which is four times less than before the update.

So, basically, the solution and recommendation is to try to keep everything up to date! :)

Comment: That's Great, Congrats.. :)